# Linking two libraries built with c++_static

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, static-linking, libc++

In the following webpage,

https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support

it states that having two libraries (libA.so, libB.so) compiled with `c++_static` breaks the one-definition rule, in which multiple symbols will be defined for c++ functions in the different libraries. This case is then undefined behaviour, where multiple bugs could occur.

However, I don't know if this also happens for the following scenario:

- I compile `libA.a` linked agsint `c++_static`
- I then compile `libB.so` and link against `c++_static` and `libA.a`

In such case, the problem would not occur, and it would be safe to link the shared library against the static library, am I correct? Or are the symbols from `libc++` embedded in `libA.a`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is safe. In fact, neither `libA.a` nor `libB.a` will be linked against `libc++`. Static libraries are not linked against their dependencies - this is done when linking executables/shared objects which use those libraries.

The only code from `libc++` that will end up in those two static libs will be (inlined) code from headers. That's not a problem.

Comment: Yeah, I thought for some reason that linking the libc++ statically was a bit different than other libraries. Awesome to know that, thank you!